# How Calculate Speed in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a problem with my data. I want to analyze speed based on "speed equation."

[image]

My data like this:

```
df

MAC T_1 X_1 Y_1 T_2 X_2 Y_2 T_3 X_3 Y_3 T_4 X_4 Y_4 T_5 X_5 Y_5 T_6 X_6 Y_6 T_7 X_7 Y_7
ID1 1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   2   3   1   3   3   1   3   4   1   4   5   1   5
ID2 6   2   5   6   2   5   7   3   5   7   3   5   8   4   5   9   5   5   10  5   4
ID3 1   1   1   2   1   2   3   1   3   3   1   3   4   1   4   5   1   5   6   2   5
```

I try to calculate speed with my code like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv") #read data
def v_2(i):
     return (df.ix[x,(5+3*(i-1))]-df.ix[x,(2+3*(i-1))])**2 + (df.ix[x,(6+3*(i-1))]-df.ix[x,(3+3*(i-1))])**2

def v(i):
    if (df.ix[x,(4+3*(i-1))]-df.ix[x,(1+3*(i-1))]) ==0:
       return 0
    else:
        return math.sqrt(v_2(i)) / (df.ix[x,(4+3*(i-1))]-df.ix[x,(1+3*(i-1))]) 
for i in range(1,7):
    for x in range(3):
        v_2(i)
        v(i)
        print((f"v：{v(i)}",f"i：{i+1}",f"ID：{x+1}"))
```

the currently result showing like this:

```
('v：0', 'i：2', 'ID：1')
('v：0', 'i：2', 'ID：2')
('v：1.0', 'i：2', 'ID：3')
('v：1.0', 'i：3', 'ID：1')
('v：1.0', 'i：3', 'ID：2')
('v：1.0', 'i：3', 'ID：3')
('v：1.0', 'i：4', 'ID：1')
('v：0', 'i：4', 'ID：2')
('v：0', 'i：4', 'ID：3')
('v：0', 'i：5', 'ID：1')
('v：1.0', 'i：5', 'ID：2')
('v：1.0', 'i：5', 'ID：3')
('v：1.0', 'i：6', 'ID：1')
('v：1.0', 'i：6', 'ID：2')
('v：1.0', 'i：6', 'ID：3')
('v：1.0', 'i：7', 'ID：1')
('v：1.0', 'i：7', 'ID：2')
('v：1.0', 'i：7', 'ID：3')
```

my expected result become `pd.Dataframe` looks like this:

```
MAC V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6
ID1 0   1   1   0   1   1
ID2 0   1   0   1   1   1
ID3 1   1   0   1   1   1
```

Would you mind to help me how to transform my data or better way to analyze the speed. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the last part of the code with this:

```
rows =[]
for i in range(1, 7):
    for x in range(3):
        v_2(i)
        v(i)
        row = [v(i), i+1, x+1]
        rows.append(row)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['v', 'i', 'ID'])
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df1, values = 'v', index=['ID'], columns = 'i').reset_index()
df2.columns = ['MAC','V1','V2','V3','V4','V5','V6']
df2.set_index('MAC', inplace=True)
print df2
```

Output:

```
      V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6
MAC                              
1    0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
2    0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
3    1.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's working. My data is enormous, how to automatically write the columns header and index without the manual typewriter?

Comment: Replace with this: `df1 = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['v', 'i', 'ID'])`
`m = df1['i'].max()`
`id_arr = [list_items for list_items in range(1, m)]`
`df2 = pd.pivot_table(df1, values = 'v', index=['ID'], columns = 'i').reset_index()`
`df2.columns = ['MAC'] + id_arr`
`df2.set_index('MAC', inplace=True)`

Comment: it's working, It very helpful. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your example code, you are not creating the Dataframe anywhere... you are just printing out: `print((f"v：{v(i)}",f"i：{i+1}",f"ID：{x+1}"))`.

An easy way is to create a dictionary with your data (even if I did not understand what data you want to store in it...) and then create a Dataframe:

```
data = {'MAC':[], 'V1':[], 'V2':[], 'V3':[], 'V4':[], 'V5':[], 'V6':[],}
for i in range(1,7):
    for x in range(3):
        data['MAX'].append('ID{}'.format(x+1))
        data['V{}'.format(i)].append(v(i))
        # do not know where to store v_2(i)
df = pandas.Dataframe(data)
```

Again I do not really understood what's inside your final Dataframe, but the above hint should be enough for you to solve the problem.

Comment: forgive me, because of Iam newbie in python and pandas. I will edit the question again. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I try this code maybe close to my expected result:

```
def v_2(i):
     return (df.ix[x,(5+3*(i-1))]-df.ix[x,(2+3*(i-1))])**2 + (df.ix[x,(6+3*(i-1))]-df.ix[x,(3+3*(i-1))])**2

def v(i):
    if (df.ix[x,(4+3*(i-1))]-df.ix[x,(1+3*(i-1))]) ==0:
       return 0
    else:
       return math.sqrt(v_2(i)) / (df.ix[x,(4+3*(i-1))]-df.ix[x,(1+3*(i-1))]) 
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv") 
df_result = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(1,int((len(df.columns)-1)/3)):
    v_result = list()
    for x in range(len(df.index)):
        v_2(i)
        v(i)
        v_result.append(v(i))
  df_result[i]=v_result
df_result.columns = ['V_{}'.format(int(i)+1) for i in df_result.columns]
df_result.index = ['ID_{}'.format(int(i)+1) for i in df_result.index]
df_result
```